# Django: earliest() and latest() require either fields as positional arguments or 'get_latest_by' in the model's Meta

Tags: python, django, django-views

Can Anyone please explain me what this error means??

I have done this in my views.py:

```
class FormListView(FormMixin, ListView):
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # From ProcessFormMixin
    form_class = self.get_form_class()
    self.form = self.get_form(form_class)

    # From BaseListView
    self.object_list = self.get_queryset()
    allow_empty = self.get_allow_empty()
    if not allow_empty and len(self.object_list) == 0:
        raise Http404(_(u"Empty list and '%(class_name)s.allow_empty' is False.")
                      % {'class_name': self.__class__.__name__})

    context = self.get_context_data(object_list=self.object_list, form=self.form)
    return self.render_to_response(context)

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return self.get(request, *args, **kwargs)


class CompanyListView(LoginRequiredMixin,FormListView):
    model = Company
    form_class  = daterangeform
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_queryset(self):
        return company.objects.filter(User=self.request.user)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(companyListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['selectdate_list'] = selectdate.objects.filter(User=self.request.user).latest()
        return context
```

And I am getting this error:

```
ValueError: earliest() and latest() require either fields as positional arguments or 'get_latest_by' in the model's Meta.
```

Can anyone please explain me what is wrong in my code and possible solution for doing it in correct way...

Thank you

Comment: You are probably looking for `.last()`. `.latest()` require a list of fields based on which you should sort.

Comment: Yeah I want to post my latest updated date for selected daterange in my template...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As specified in the documentation for [**`latest(*fields)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.latest):

> Returns the latest object in the table **based on the given
> field(s).**
>
> This example returns the latest `Entry` in the table, according to the
> `pub_date` field:
>
> ```
> Entry.objects.latest('pub_date')
> ```

So if you want to obtain the latest object with respect to a field (for example `updated_date`), you can write this as:

```
selectdate.objects.filter(
    User=self.request.user
).latest('updated_date')
```

You *can* however use the `latest()` *without* parameters, given you specified the order for this in the `Meta` class of the model, like:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    class Meta:
        get_latest_by = ['name']
```

In that case

```
Foo.objects.latest()
```

will give the `Foo` object with the *maximum* `name` (if we here compare the names lexicographically).

Comment: I have done this now its giving me this error ''selectdate' object is not iterable"

Comment: @NiladryKar: that is because this is a `selectdate` *object*, not a `selectdate_list` (not a collection, but a single element). How are you supposed to iterate over a single element?

Comment: Ooooo...What do I have to do in my template then to show the latest selectdate object????

Comment: Rename the variable to `context['selectdate']`, and thus in the template you can use `{{ selectdate }}`, or if you want to render an attribute `{{ selectdate.some_attribute }}` (it is just a normal model object, so you process it like that).

Comment: I just want to show the latest date as when the user chose the dates the template should display the selected dates by the user...Can You tell me is my process of accomplishing this is right???

Comment: @NiladryKar: you can show this with `{{ selectdate.update_date }}` (well the name of the attribute can be different). But here an aggregate might be more appropriate, given I understand the problem correctly.

Comment: @NiladryKar: (a) is `update_date` the name of the field that stores this update timestamp; and (b) did you *rename* the context-variable, like `context['selectdate'] = ...` not `context['selectdate_list'] = ...`.

Comment: Yeah I have done that....As you can see I have done this, "context['selectdate'] = selectdate.objects.filter(User=self.request.user).latest('Start_Date')"...

Comment: @NiladryKar: and the template looks like `{{ selectdate.Start_Date }}`?

Comment: No  like this '{{ selectdate }}'...As you have said in your earlier comments

Comment: @NiladryKar: that is when you render the *object* itself, not one of its *attributes*. Please try to implement some "concept hygiene" in your nomenclature.

Comment: I just want to show the updated 'Start_Date' of the user whenever he selects the date

Comment: @NiladryKar: and how does he select a date?

Comment: OOOO...Actually I have to just create a update view for that....Sorry...Your answer always helps me a lot...Thank you@Willem Van Onsem

Comment: @NiladryKar: a database does *not* keep track of what record was inserted/edited most recently. So you have to add a "timestamp" for that yourself. As said before `.latest(..)` does *not* return the item that was latest added/edited/..., it is simply a shortcut of `.order_by(..).last()`.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is already here in [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#latest)

Well, the error you're encountering, "ValueError: earliest() and latest() require either fields as positional arguments or 'get_latest_by' in the model's Meta," is due to the use of the latest() method in the line:

```
context['selectdate_list'] = selectdate.objects.filter(User=self.request.user).latest()
```

To resolve this issue, you need to specify a field for ordering in the latest() method or define the get_latest_by attribute in the model's Meta class.
In your SelectDate model (assuming it's a model):

```
class SelectDate(models.Model):
    # your fields here

    class Meta:
        # Specify the field for ordering
        ordering = ['-your_date_field']
```

Or, in the query itself, by passing the field as an argument to latest():

```
context['selectdate_list'] = selectdate.objects.filter(User=self.request.user).latest('your_date_field')
```